# DBcontext class in separate class library and Asp.net core webapi application is a separate project

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, ef-code-first, asp.net-core-webapi

Package manager console image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0Edv.png)

Solution explorer image [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zInGf.png)

1. 1. I kept start project as Sample.API and Default Project as
      DataRepository\SampleApplicationDatabase. I am trying to add
      migration by giving command like this: Add-Migration addingtable
      -Context SampleApplicationContext"

      it is throwing error like below "Unable to create an object of type 'SampleApplicationContext'. Add an implementation of
      'IDesignTimeDbContextFactory' to the project, or see
      https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728 for additional
      patterns supported at design time. mypackagemanagerconsole"

      Iam not undersatnding what mistake i have made, can one help me to sort out of this issue, thanks inadvance.

Appsetting of Sample.Api

```
{
  "SampleApplicationConnectionstring": {
    "ConnectionString": "Server=TEKFRIDAY281;Database=SampleApplication;User ID=sa;Password=friday123!;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Integrated Security=false"
    
      },
      "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
          "Default": "Information",
          "Microsoft": "Warning",
          "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
        }
      },
      "AllowedHosts": "*"
    }
```

Startup of Sample.Api

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using API_Interface;
using DataAccessLayer;
using IRepository;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Repository;
using SampleApplicationDatabase;

namespace Sample.API
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddTransient<IData, Data>();
            services.AddTransient<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddDbContext<SampleApplicationContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionString")));
          
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

SampleApplicationContext.cs file which is in DataRepository

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using SampleApplicationModels;
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace SampleApplicationDatabase
{
    public class SampleApplicationContext:DbContext
    {
        public SampleApplicationContext(DbContextOptions<SampleApplicationContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<AdminCredentials> AdminCredentials { get; set; }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            foreach (var relationship in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes().SelectMany(e => e.GetForeignKeys()))
            {
                relationship.DeleteBehavior = DeleteBehavior.Restrict;
            }

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi can anyone solve my above mentioned issue Iam working on this issue since 3 days, please help me, thanks in advance

Comment: Use your Sample.API as the startup and project, and then make sure that your Sample.API references the Class library project, and then migrate.

Comment: sorry, it didn't help me. I think the problem is with my start up and default projects i added my class library project which has dbcontext as referance to startup project(Sample.API) even though migrations are failed. Can anyone help me what mistake i have made.